# How to browse every 5 records using MYSQL and jquery ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am looking for solution where using jquery I want to display 5 records per page and need Next/Prev functionality. So when user click on next button or image it will fetch data from PHP, Mysql and displays it.

SO kind of pagination but using Next/Prev

Thanks & Regards,
web programmer

Comment: well that still sounds exactly like pagination, only cutting out the part where you loop through and display all the page links...or rather, just narrowing the loop range to -1 to +1

Comment: Here is a tutorial to help with this: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

Comment: there is one jquery example for pagination but there is no example for NEXT/Prev using jqueru PHP mysql can somebody let me know if they have any sample with Next/prev using jquery php mysql 

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very detailed, but I'll take a swing at it.  Datatables is a great plugin for jQuery that will display records in a table.  It supports pagination, with Next & Previous  buttons.  Check it out at [www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net)

You can see an example of the Next & Previous pagination [here](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html).
You can see an example of PHP serving data to datatables [here](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html).

Comment: +1 for Datatables, love that plugin, need html not htm on your example link for next prev pagination

Comment: basically my question is same like this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383840/jquery-pagination-question

in my case i want to display data in DIV tag, 5 records in 5 div tags then on click of Next button it will call PHP page and it will show next 5 records

Comment: Datatables will paginate data serverd by PHP as you are requesting.  however it does so using tables to display the data.  Please update you question with more specific requirements if this does not meet your needs.  I have updated my response with a link to the Datatables PHP example

Comment: @nagy You don't want to display tabular data using divs, it's not bad design to use a table to display table data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, look at the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html) plugin (along with the pager plugin as well)